# ionic 2 - How to access component function from parent

Tags: cordova, typescript, ionic2

I have custom loading (SearchingModalComponent)
i want to call function show() in SearchingModalComponent

**SearchingModalComponent**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'searching-modal',
    templateUrl: 'searching-modal.html'
})
export class SearchingModalComponent {
    public show_classname: any;

    constructor() {
        this.show_classname = ""
    }

    public show() {
        this.show_classname = "busy";
    }

    hide() {
        this.show_classname = "";
    }
}
```

**app.modules.ts**

```
import { SearchingModalComponent } from '../components/searching-modal/searching-modal';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyApp,
        HomePage,
        ScanPage,
        SearchingModalComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
    ],
    bootstrap: [IonicApp],
    entryComponents: [
        MyApp,
        HomePage,
        ScanPage
    ],
    providers: [{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}, [ScreenSaver]]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    template: `
        <ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
        <searching-modal id="loading" #Searching></searching-modal>
    `
})
```

**root page**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SearchingModalComponent } from '../../components/searching-modal/searching-modal';

@Component({
    selector: 'page-scan',
    templateUrl: 'scan.html'
})
export class ScanPage {

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController
    , public ScreenSaverPrivid: ScreenSaver
    , public SearchingModal: SearchingModalComponent
    ) { }

    openLoading() {
        this.SearchingModal.show();
        console.log('openLoading');
    }
}
```

> system information:
>
> - Cordova CLI: 6.0.0
> - Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.3
> - Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.14
> - Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
> - Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.46
> - ios-deploy version: Not installed
> - ios-sim version: Not installed
> - OS: Windows 10
> - Node Version: v6.9.1
> - Xcode version: Not installed

**EDIT**
**[Solved]**  Thank you **Hadrien TOMA**

> move  `<searching-modal id="loading" #Searching></searching-modal>`
>   to
>   scan.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `ViewChild` and to put a reference for your child in your parent template (as you have already done), [here](http://learnangular2.com/viewChild/) you can see a simple example of how to do that.

**EDIT : Adding some tips**

Moreover, you have to call `@ViewChild` in the component relative to the template that has the reference, in your case you have two options : move `<searching-modal id="loading" #Searching></searching-modal>` to `scan.html` or move `openLoading(){...}` and `@ViewChild(...)...` to `app.component.ts`. The first option is for me the best.